# Probability Question involving dice

Tags: probability

A fair die is rolled four times. Consider the events:

A={the numbers in the first three rolls are all different}

B={the number in the fourth roll is not a repetition of any of the numbers in the first three rolls}

What is the probability for the following situations:

1. P(A)
2. P(B)
3. P(A|$B^c$)

Thanks!

Edit:

I have found the answer to P($A$)= $\frac{(6*5*4*6)}{6^4}$ = $\frac{4}{9}$

I still have no clue how to do 2 and 3.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  For the second question, consider cases, depending on whether one, two, or three different numbers appear in the first three rolls.

Comment: I got 125/216 for Q2 and 60/91 for Q3. Do you mind confirming if its correct?

Comment: Yes, both of your answers are correct.